# Dropping ß entirely

Tags: eszett

I'm learning German and was wondering if I could completely drop ß (Eszett) and replace it with ss in all instances where ß is used. I know that the Swiss don't use ß. Is this practical? Can this become a problem when communicating with Germans?

Comment: I'm afraid, this question is entirely opinion-based. In my opinion you would be understood, but immediately detected as foreigner (or someone with a wrong keyboard not investing effort). Your proposal is pretty similar to replacing umlauts as *ä* by *ae*. I would not try to save effort on such easy topics.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5611/is-it-an-error-when-i-do-not-use-ß-when-it-is-necessary?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it an error when I do not use ß when it is necessary?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5611/is-it-an-error-when-i-do-not-use-%c3%9f-when-it-is-necessary)

Comment: Was ist daran eine Frage der Meinung? "Die Maße von Susi spiegeln ihre Masse wider." Noch Fragen? Ich vote nicht für reopen, da es als Duplikat geschlossen bleiben soll, siehe @PiedPiper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are creating ambiguity. After the latest spelling reform, people assume ß makes the preceding vowel long. In German long vs. short vowel is **always** significant to meaning:

> Maße *← long a — measures*
>
> Masse *← short a — mass*

In Switzerland, people live with that ambiguity. It's only a minor obstacle in Swiss German, which is a challenge of its own.